# how to reduce signal noises

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, signal-processing, wave, function-generator

I am trying generate guided waves on simple metallic plate through piezo-ceramic material, I place two piezo on the surface of the plate at the different location and through Arbitrary pulse generator, I generate the Gaussian pulse of 150KHz and excite the one piezo. This excitation generate guided waves which is sensed by the other piezo. but the problem is, the output signal has very high noises and very low SNR ratio, I hardly even see the signal on the oscilloscope, but whenever I switch to the normal sine wave of the same frequency, and shut off the arbitrary and burst option, then the output signal will have very high resolution and SNR value.
Please someone guide me how to reduce signal noises,

[image]

Comment: What is your calculated signal?

Comment: you mean the input signal? It is simply a 5 cycle wave pulse, windowed by the Gaussian function with central frequency of 150KHz.

Comment: What happens if you increase the number of cycles to eg. 50, 500, etc.?

Comment: I cant increase the cycle, I need a small pulse to generate the guided wave in the material,

Comment: So what exactly is a "guided wave" in this scenario?

Comment: Actually peizo convert electrical signals into mechanical work and so the peizo is attached with metallic structure, its motion generate mechanical stress waves that propagate contained within the structural boundaries, that is the guided wave. The wave requires small pulse of varying frequency,

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the pulse response and the CW response would suggest that something in your system has a very narrow bandwidth — perhaps the metal plate itself? The transducers?

If you want a more specific response, you'll have to provide a lot more data about your setup.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see how this answers the title of the question. Being half an answer (*"If you want a more specific response"*), shouldn't this not rather be a comment asking for more information, as in other phrasing of (*perhaps the metal plate itself? The transducers?*)

Comment: @Huisman: The title is somewhat garbled -- if you read the text, you'll find that the OP wants to improve the signal-to-noise ratio for his wideband pulses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I have mechanical background, so I coundnt figure out the source of these noises. As u can see the blue signals, the output one has very low amplitude, where each box has value of 50mV, Moreover, when I remove the probes, these noises still persist there. Can u please guide me what data I should provide to avoid these noises.